# How many Hamiltonian paths in a tournament?

Tags: graph-theory

I've got this question in a quiz. A tournament pictured below. How many Hamiltonian paths are there? Also I need to justify the answer

[image]

Comment: How is that a "tournament"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex $C$ has a zero out-degree, and so this must be the end of any Hamiltonian path. This reduces the problem to how many Hamiltonian paths are on the vertices $abde$.

We can see that $a$ must be followed by $e$, or come at the end, which reduces the number of test cases to just $12$. These can easily be enumerated, especially as $daeb$ is a Hamiltonian cycle.

$aebd$

$baed$, $bdae$

$daeb$

$ebda$

So there are $5$ Hamiltonian paths in total.

Comment: Good answer. Any way I can get it using adjacency matrix?

Comment: @user3600124; you might be better using permutations with a set of rules, in this case e cannot follow a, etc...